# In a spring.config.import factory how do you access properties in the invoking document?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I am creating a spring.config.import factory and can't see how to access properties from the invoking(parent) document

```
# mish-mash of properties without a common prefix
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

# now I want to read key1, key2 inside the factory
spring.config.import = myfactory:
```

Inside my implementation

```
@Configuration
public class MyFactoryResolver  implements ConfigDataLocationResolver<MyResource>, Ordered {

@Override
public List<MyResource> resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext context, ConfigDataLocation location) {

// how do I get the values or key1 and key2
// tried
binder.bind("key1", String.class).get(); // FAIL
// key1 needs to be in a higher source like environment KEY1=VALUE1
}

// tried as field
@Value("${key1}")
String key1; // always null 
// cannot inject; too early in life-cycle ?
}
```

Now [spring-cloud-client](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/tree/main/spring-cloud-config-client) can do this

```
spring.cloud.config.username = johndoe
spring.cloud.config.password = john's password
spring.config.import = configserver:http://myserver.com
```

— so clearly it is possible to read a property value from the parent doc.

But I can't see how this code works — this code is baroque/mysterious to me:

- it doesn't read a property like  `spring.cloud.config.username` simply
- instead it creates a sidekick `@ConfigurationProperties ClientConfigProperties` bean (how?) that wraps all `spring.cloud.config.*` key/values. This bean can't be injected (too early in the life-cycle??), so it is retrieved from a `Binder` and then all the properties are available; so if these properties can be
  read off a sidekick, why I can't I read them easily...
- my properties don't have a standard prefix so it is not easy to create a `@ConfigurationProperties` sidekick
- ...also in the code of spring-cloud-config-client you sometimes see `new ClientConfigProperties(...)` — I always thought this was forbidden in DI-land as the container won't be able to manage it for you.

TL;DR - what I am looking for is a way to read property/key values from the  context(binder?) of the document or a sister document that invoked the factory; without having to create a side-kick bean and forcing all properties to confirm to prefix-naming. (This is a legacy application where property names were not enforced...).

Update: I attemped to duplicate the sidekick pattern — standardised property names to a prefix and one segment, created a holder `@ConfiguationProperties` bean and added it as an `EnableAutoConfiguration` factory (copy-pasta from spring-cloud-config). Copied code:

```
   private MyProperties resolveHook(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean registered = context.getBootstrapContext().isRegistered(MyProperties.class);
        System.out.println("RESOLVER: MyProperties is registered = " + registered);
        if (registered) {
            return context.getBootstrapContext().get(MyProperties.class);
        }

        Binder localBinder = context.getBinder();
        BindHandler localHandler = context.getBootstrapContext().getOrElse(BindHandler.class, null);
        System.out.println("RESOLVER: BindHandler is null? " + (localHandler == null));

        BindResult<MyProperties> object = localBinder.bind(MyProperties.PREFIX,
                Bindable.of(MyProperties.class), localHandler);
        System.out.println("RESOLVER: object is bound? " + (object.isBound()));
        if (object.isBound()) {
            MyProperties properties = object.get();
            context.getBootstrapContext().registerIfAbsent(MyProperties.class, InstanceSupplier.of(properties));
            System.out.println(
                    "RESOLVER: register object of type " + (properties.getClass().getName()) + " " + properties);
            return properties;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Holy cow - this actually works - the sidekick bean is created and all the fields are injected from the parent document. Then the resolver can read off the property values — however this is surely the most obscure and round-about way of doing things, and there has to be a simpler method?

Comment: I don't think there is a "better way". We do the same thing in `spring-cloud-kubernetes`, see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/blob/main/spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/commons/config/KubernetesConfigDataLocationResolver.java#L179)

Comment: what you might want to do is use `bindOrCreate` btw, since this method will also resolve `@DefaultValue`s (if you have them)

Comment: @Eugene - my `ConfigDataLoader` makes network calls to a host:port which is why I need to read key1/key2 from application.properties.It accesses an internal API using HttpClient and gets back an entity in properties format.

Comment: @xerx593 - thanks; that was my bad in the sample code - now fixed. I had put the Value annotation on a field but that ended up always null.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for the answer goes to the Spring Team (philwebb at GH) when I posted this as a question to the Spring repository https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32854:

I mistakenly used the binder that can be constructor injected when implementing a `ConfigDataLocationResolver`. Instead one should use the binder from the first parameter of the overriden methods:

```
// Constructor
public MyResolver(Log log, Binder binder) {
        super();
        this.log = log;
        // don't use this object to access properties
        // from the invoking properties file
        this.binder = binder;
}

@Override
boolean isResolvable(ConfigDataLocationResolverContext context...) {
    Binder localBinder = context.getBinder();
    // this object has access to properties defined in the invoking
    // parent application.properties

}
```

TL;DR there are number of binder objects one can access (constructor injection, from a context) — one should be using the `Binder` from the context and not the constructor.